# DirectX - GetSurfaceLevel Performance Issue

Tags: c++, winapi, directx

I'm implementing deferred shading in a directx 9 application. My method of deferred shading requires 3 render targets( color, position, and normal ). It is necessary to:

1. set the render targets in the device at the beginning of the 'render' function
2. draw the data to them in the 'rt pass'
3. remove the render targets from the device( so as not to draw over them during subsequent passes)
4. set the render targets as textures for subsequent passes so that the effect can recall data 'drawn' to the rt's in the 'rt pass'...

This method works fine, however, I am experiencing performance issues. I've narrowed them down to two function calls:

```
IDirect3DTexture9::GetSurfaceLevel()
IDirect3DDevice9::SetRenderTarget()
```

Here is code to set render target:

```
IDirect3DDevice9 *pd3dDevice = CEffectManager::GetDevice();
IDirect3DTexture9 *pRT = CEffectManager::GetColorRT();
IDirect3DSurface9 *pSrf = NULL;

pRT->GetSurfaceLevel( 0, &pSrf );

pd3dDevice->SetRenderTarget( 0, pSrf );
```

PIX indicates that the duration( cycles ) of the call to GetSurfaceLevel() is very high ~1/2 ms per call( Duration / Total Duration * 1 / FrameRate ). Because it is necessary to get 3 surfaces, combined, the duration is too high! Its more than 4 times greater than the combined draw calls...

I tried to eliminate the call to GetSurfaceLevel() by storing a pointer to the surface during render target creation...oddly enough, the SetRenderTarget() function assumed the same duration( when before its duration was negligible ). Here is altered code:

```
IDirect3DDevice9 *pd3dDevice = CEffectManager::GetDevice();
IDirect3DSurface9 *pSrf = CEffectManager::GetColorSurface();

pd3dDevice->SetRenderTarget( 0, pSrf );
```

Is there a way around this performance issue? Why does the second method take as long as the first? It seems as though the process within IDirect3DDevice9::SetRenderTarget() simply takes time...is there a device state that I can set to help performance?

Update:
I've implemented the following code in order to better test performance:

```
IDirect3DDevice9 *pd3dDevice = CEffectManager::GetDevice();
IDirect3DTexture9 *pRT = CEffectManager::GetColorRT();
IDirect3DSurface9 *pSRF = NULL;
IDirect3DQuery9 *pEvent = NULL;
LARG_INTEGER lnStart, lnStop, lnFrequency;

// create query
pd3dDevice->CreateQuery( D3DQUERYTYPE_EVENT, &pEvent );

// insert 'end' marker
pEvent->Issue( D3DISSUE_END );

// flush command buffer
while( S_FALSE == pEvent->GetData( NULL, 0, D3DGETDATA_FLUSH ) );

// get start time
QueryPerformanceCounter( &lnStart );

// api call
pRT->GetSurfaceLevel();

// insert 'end' marker
pEvent->Issue( D3DISSUE_END )

// flush the command buffer
while( S_FALSE == pEvent->GetData( NULL, 0, D3DGETDATA_FLUSH ) );

QueryPerformanceCounter( &lnStop );
QueryPerformanceFrequency( &lnFreq );

lnStop.QuadPart -= lnStart.QuadPart;
float fElapsedTime = ( float )lnStop.QuadPart / ( float )lnFreq.QuadPart;
```

fElapsedTime on average measured 10 - 50 microseconds
I performed the same test on IDirect3DDevice9::SetRenderTarget() and the results on average measured 5 - 30 microseconds...

This data is much better than what I got from PIX...It suggests that there is not as much of a delay as I thought, however, the framerate is drastically reduced using deferred shading...this seems to be the most likely source for the loss of performance...did I effectively query the device?

Comment: Did you try timing with IDirect3DQuery9 in addition to PIX? Do you use MRT? What GPU/driver you have? Calling SetRenderTarget isn't free but shouldn't be a bottleneck for a simple deferred renderer.

Comment: GPU: ATI Radeon HD 4550, up to 8 RTs...[GPU specs](http://www.amd.com/us/products/desktop/graphics/ati-radeon-hd-4000/hd-4550/Pages/ati-radeon-hd-4550-specifications.aspx) I will try IDirect3DQuery9 tonight...

Comment: i've tried querying the device...my implementation was added above...better results...so long as i have correctly queried the device

Comment: another function that is causing a delay as it turns out is IDirect3DDevice9::ColorFill()...it measures ~1/10 -> 1/2 milliseconds according the device query...is it possible that PIX is inaccurate when measuring duration? Is this due to mode changes between user and kernel modes caused by the filling of the command buffer? GetSurfaceLevel() and SetRenderTarget seem to be within reason now...

Comment: You can force a flush by locking the backbuffer after each command. With one API command sent to kmd at a time you can instrument with rdtsc or QueryPerformanceCounter to have an idea on how reliable your instrumentation setup is. Also, do you enable the debug layer when you create the device?

Comment: What is your use of IDirect3DDevice9::ColorFill()? It can be slow if you fill a large region.
When clearing your MRT use IDirect3DDevice9::Clear to clear everything at once + benefit from fast-clear.

Comment: I do enable debug...found rdtsc guide [here](http://www.ccsl.carleton.ca/~jamuir/rdtscpm1.pdf)...i was using ColorFill() to set the color of the 'color' RT to black( 0 )...i have since switched to IDirect3DDevice9::Clear() thanks!